# IntelliJ doesn't suggest imports for methods

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, import, akka

I have encountered a problem that my IntelliJ IDE doesn't find and suggest some imports for Scala Akka. The example is it couldn't find anything from `akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._`
Simply, when I write `path("somestring")` method it is highlighted as error and import is not suggested.

I have correct imports and I have tried refreshing imports in my `build.sbt`.
I have also tried disabling Coursier for build.sbt since I have heard it may sometimes cause troubles (`ThisBuild / useCoursier := false`).
I tried updating caches, invalidating caches and of course restarting IDE and reimporting project. None of this worked. However, when I have manually added import

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
```

everything works fine.
I wonder what could be the case and how to fix it since manually adding imports is very uncomfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto import works on the class/trait/object level not the method level so if you qualify method name

```
Directives.path()
```

it should work

[image]

however if you just write method name

```
path()
```

then it suggests to create a method

[image]